# Toggle having the same class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a problem using jQuery for toggle. When i have the same class name for some tags, i would like to get the one event only on clicking the button.

Some of my code are below, and if i click a button named '1', it shows the rows of '2' and '5' since they have the same class name 'detail'. however, if i click '1', i would like to show only the row of '2'.

I am not willing to use different name since it is supposed to have lots of rows having toggle function. which means i need to have many names for each tag.

Please help me with some solution and advice, thank you.

---Script----

```
    <script>
            $(".button").click(function () {
                $(".detail").slideToggle("slow");
            });
            $(".button2").click(function () {
                $(".detail2").slideToggle("slow");
            });
    </script>
```

---HTML-----

```
   <table class="w850 table">
        <tr>
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="button" value="1" class="button"/>
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Scan
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Status
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Ship Type
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="detail" style="display: none">
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="button" value="2" class="button2"/>
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Scan
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Status
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Ship Type
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="detail2" style="display: none">
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="button" value="3" />
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Scan
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Status
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Ship Type
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="button" value="4" class="button"/>
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Scan
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Status
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Ship Type
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="detail" style="display: none">
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="button" value="5" class="button2"/>
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Scan
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Status
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Ship Type
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="detail2" style="display: none">
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td class="w50">
                <input type="button" value="6" />
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Scan
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Status
            </td>
            <td class="w250">
                Ship Type
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").siblings(".detail:first").slideToggle("slow");
});
$(".button2").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").siblings(".detail2:first").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

This will select first .detail row

You can have a look at here http://jsfiddle.net/4KP9Y/2/ for working code

Comment: Thanks, but it still shows both of '2' and '4' when i click '1'.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is found in the rows you can probably do something like this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").siblings(".detail2").show()
});
```

You probably want to look at jQuery's functions for traversing the DOM. Meaning getting from here to there: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: Thanks, but when i click button '1', it will show '2'. and on clicking '2', it will show '3'. so the code you provided me is supposed to ".detail" not ".detail2", isnt it? Sorry for giving a confusion.
I have changed code and tried it but still show both rows of '2' and '4'...

Comment: As others have said without knowing where the buttons show up on your page it's difficult to figure out their relationship with each row. I still think learning about traversing might help you come to a solution.

Comment: I see. I also try to find a solution. Thank you anyway.